# SMD transistor on motherboard is blown after a big spark; case fan no longer works

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, fan

So I installed a new fan and upon turning on the computer there was a huge spark with loud bang. Everything stopped working until I unplugged power from motherboard. Now upon boot, computer says one of the fans has failed. Works otherwise. Upon close inspection I see a broken transistor (not sure proper terminology). I mean it cracked open.

The computer is working OK, but I keep worrying about sparks and hence a fire problem. It may not happen immediately. Can someone, with deeper knowledge in hardware, advise whether motherboard change should be done or I shouldn't worry about this or what are the concerns with this situation?

I've included the photo of the damage below, its right next to the fan connector (which now stays unplugged). The model of this seems to be PA102FDG.

[image: PA102FDG]

Comment: You would have to replace the broken transistor which sounds out of your technical ability to do so.  Its not clear which part is damaged from your screenshot.  In other words if you are that worried you would need to replace the entire motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound, it's the square thing with the diagonal crack in it, just below the brown Capacitor. It's also definitely a transistor that's broken. Data sheet for that particular part: http://www.cheertech.com.tw/Niko-sem/Data%20sheet%5CPA102FDG.pdf

Comment: @MichaelFrank - I didn't see the crack originally.  Doesn't really matter Daniil clear does not have the technical skills to remove, clean, and replace the part.

Comment: @Ramhound - is that even possible to do? I'd give a crack at it. The computer is pretty old, wouldn't feel that bad burning it.

Comment: @Daniil - Its possible no guarantee it will work.  It also requires soldering skills, soldering supplies, and the actual replacement IC.

Comment: It's probably not worth trying to replace the failed SMD transistor. I would just replace the board.

Comment: The most important question of all - is this a fire hazard? Not an expert in transistors, no idea how they behave when split in half.

Comment: The part would be the cheapest part of the entire repair process. I would probably give it a go.

Comment: Just because: http://www.cheertech.com.tw/Niko-sem/Data%20sheet%5CPA102FDG.pdf ;)

Comment: @techie007 I beat you to it already. :)

Comment: Your first question should be; "what caused the transistor to be subjected to so much current that it blew". Unless you are familiar with circuit fault-finding and replacing SMTs, replace the board. The manhours alone for a tech to do the work probably exceeds the cost of a new board.

Comment: @Tog - I know what caused it - lack of sleep and hence concentration when installing the fan. Are you suggesting this cracked transistor is simply the visible component of the failure but there can be more? My original question, to which there are no actual answers as everyone seems to be concerned with soldering, was regarding fire hazard.

Comment: Without a cct diagram and test equipment there really is no way to determine what else might have been damaged or weakened. Personally, I would be unwilling to continue using the board. Right now your processor, memory and expansion cards can be salvaged. If some other weakened component goes short, who knows?

Comment: Also, from the picture, the cap right above the transistor appears to be bulging... Hard to tell for sure, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF that fan isn't necessary for proper cooling, you can probably run the motherboard just fine without it. At the low currents available to a fan you're not likely to see a fire hazard.

That said, if its an older setup as you've mentioned, you might just be better off replacing/upgrading it.

I don't recommend attempting to replace the SMD transistor yourself. SMD (de)soldering is quite a bit more difficult than through-hole.